# Read as well as Append a file by different programmes simultaneously using java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, file-io

I am working in java 
my goal is that I have to read from a file and at the same time I have to append that file by another code 
it will be like an executable abc will be reading file 'myfile.txt' and another executable xyz will appending 'myfile.txt'.
Is it possible , what concept I should apply to get it work .
**I read somewhere that it depends on OS then while working on android AVD will it be possible ? **

Comment: this because I am receiving a very large file from server , and while receiving it I am also using it received contents.

Comment: will that be possible in same executable ? that is in multi threading reading and writing the file

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this question.  It is clear what the OP is asking, and it is certainly implementable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to do that, though not particularly efficiently.  For example, you can implement this kind of thing using the Apache Commons [`Tailer`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) class.

---

However, I can't help thinking that you would be better off using a "pipe" that one application writes to and the next one reads from.  Since Android has Linux underneath, there should be a way to create and use pipes.

And if you want to do this within a single Android application, you can use Java intra-process pipes; e.g. `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`.

Comment: thank you very much Stephen for your answer and support , the people trying to close this question because they are unaware of the application I am developing and I don't wish to disclose my idea .Your answer and 95K points tell alot